# Is -TypeError: array_flip(): Argument #1 must be of type array, string given- a php 8, Drupal 9, civicrm 5.55.2 or all combined Issue?

Tags: drupal-9, php8

PHP 8 TypeError I encountered when making adjustments to the search preferences, unchecking not needed fields and checking new custom fields. no autocomplete drop down anymore and when I TRY to go back into search preferences, a fatal error is thrown with:

`The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later. TypeError: array_flip(): Argument #1 ($array) must be of type array, string given in array_flip() (line 380 of /code/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Admin/Form/SettingTrait.php). array_flip('external_identifiersort_namecitycustom_Annuity_Balancecustom_PAP_Balancecustom_Pension_Credits_to_Date') (Line: 380) CRM_Admin_Form_Setting::reorderSortableOptions('quicksearch_options', Array) (Line: 224) CRM_Admin_Form_Setting->addFieldsDefinedInSettingsMetadata() (Line: 66) CRM_Admin_Form_Setting->buildQuickForm() (Line: 47) CRM_Admin_Form_Setting_Search->buildQuickForm() (Line: 689) CRM_Core_Form->buildForm() (Line: 76).... and more..`

Is this just because of php 8? I am on Drupal 9 and it requires php 8, but will work on 7.4, i thinks.. ? any fixes on the horizon?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this has been a bug for a while, not strictly related to php 8, it just crashes with php 8. Can you file an issue at https://lab.civicrm.org with the stack trace?

By the way drupal 9 will run with php 7.4 and it won't be removed from drupal 9, just drupal 10.

EDIT: Fix is at https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/25170

Comment: Thanks for that, drupal Fails on the update screens because of php 7.4 . I will open an issue thanks!

Comment: Ok I see what you mean if you're not already on 9.4 then it gives a warning about 7.4 that looks like a fail but it's just a warning and you can click continue, or use drush.

Comment: yeah, for sure.. this issue is fatal on php8 and wonky in 7.4. pretty sure I just figured out why.  see https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/q/43074/14046 I will update the Issue as well.. Feeling much better today ..

Answer (score 1):

A roll back to php 7.4 along with deletion of template_c files seems to bring back a working environment. As in, php7.4 does not fatal error on this however the issue persists.. Just tested in Drupal 7 as well and any change with search preferences causes things to break.