# Way to reset search preferences, display preferences when admin page inaccessible?

Tags: drupal-9, php8

In Refrence to my [related issue](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/q/43060/14046) how do I re-write the default preferences back to what they were when first CiviCRM was installed? Admin screen no longer accessible after search preferences changes..

Drupal 9, PHP 8, CiviCRM 5.55.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have [cv](https://github.com/civicrm/cv) installed? You can do

`cv ev  '\Civi::settings()->set("quicksearch_options", array (  0 => "sort_name",  1 => "contact_id",  2 => "external_identifier",  3 => "first_name",  4 => "last_name",  5 => "email",  6 => "phone_numeric",  7 => "street_address",  8 => "city",  9 => "postal_code",  10 => "job_title"));'`

Alternatively if you have database access you can do

`UPDATE civicrm_setting set value='a:11:{i:0;s:9:"sort_name";i:1;s:10:"contact_id";i:2;s:19:"external_identifier";i:3;s:10:"first_name";i:4;s:9:"last_name";i:5;s:5:"email";i:6;s:13:"phone_numeric";i:7;s:14:"street_address";i:8;s:4:"city";i:9;s:11:"postal_code";i:10;s:9:"job_title";}' where name='quicksearch_options';`

Comment: I understand cv runs on your local environment or a secure shell on remote server. this is hosted at PANTHEON and there is no shell access. I have drush available .. the SQL will help! THANKS