# Search Preferences set a custom Profile quick search - autocomplete fields drop down stops working. This is Why!

Tags: custom-fields, profile, custom-search, quicksearch, autocomplete

pretty sure this is related to [TypeError: array_flip():](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/q/43060/14046)

New install, CiviCRM 5.55.2 on drupal9 php7.4

- setup few custom fields for INDIVIDUAL in new group, fields searchable. Not View only!
- Create profile with fields, used for search listing, directory.. all fields searchable. and result
- Set new profile as default contact - save

Autocomplete fails to list fields. clear cache, reset DB-triggers rebuild menu, etc no effect. return to search preferences, and get...
[image]

If you remove the custom profile, everything returns to normal and fields list under autocomplete again..

With this in mind I

- went back to my Profile and added a couple CONTACT fields, email, etc..
- set profile in search preferences
- Autocomplete stops working again
- I select another option in autocomplete contact search PHONE, etc and save.

Autocomplete field lists come back! with all the previous fields selected.
[image]

*adding contact fields with individual custom fields was not the fix.
Selecting deselecting any of the fields, reordering the list causes it to break. whether or not a custom search profile is used or not.*

Answer (score 1):

There is a fix at https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/25170, also with an upgrade script to fix any broken values in the database.